# "`GLIBCXX_3.4.32' not found" error at runtime. GCC 13.2.0

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, libstdc++

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS in WSL.
I successfully built and installed GCC 13.2.0 from source. This is how I configured it:

```bash
../gcc/configure --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++
```

g++ was then successfully installed in `/usr/local/bin/g++` after all the right steps. But when I tried to run a simple Hello World application, I got the following runtime error:

```
./hello: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.32' not found (required by ./hello)
```

It seems that the program is not being linked with the latest built libstdc++, or maybe it wasn't properly built at all. How can I fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: You need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the location of the built `libstdc++.so.6`. The system library `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` is not compatible with your `hello`.

Comment: @273K Thanks, I found the built library, its path is `/usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`. But setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to this path didn't work, it still tries to link with the system library.

Comment: You should not set that file path. You should set the base path `/usr/local/lib64`. Usually it is described in the guide for gcc build.

Answer (score 13):

I also encountered the same issue, and this is how I solved it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libstdc++6
```

It seems like the /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.32' is for gcc13, so we need to update this file.

check the result:

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

output:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_3.4.29
GLIBCXX_3.4.30
GLIBCXX_3.4.31
GLIBCXX_3.4.32
GLIBCXX_TUNABLES
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

Comment: This helped me figure out a problem with some packages failing in Gentoo after using a binary host. The path was `strings /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`